# Installing NPF Driver Manually

Tags: driver, winpcap

I want install NPF driver without Packet.dll and wpcap.dll.
I extract Winpcap-4.1.exe using 7zip and copy npf.sys to C:/Windows/ System32/drivers.
I also have made such registry

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ services \ NPF]
>   "Type" = dword: 00000001 "Start" = dword: 00000002 "ErrorControl" =
>   dword: 00000001 "ImagePath" = hex (2):
>   73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d, 00,33,00,32,00,5c, 00,64,00, \
>   72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c, 00,6e, 00,70,00,66,00,2e,
>   00,73,00,79, \    00,73,00,00,00 "DisplayName" = "NetGroup Packet
>   Filter Driver" "TimestampMode" = dword: 00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ services \ NPF \
>   Enum] "0" = "Root \ \ LEGACY_NPF 0000" "Count" = dword: 00000001
>   "NextInstance" = dword: 00000001

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better compile the NPF driver by yourself. And it's simple:

1. Get Winpcap source file: http://www.winpcap.org/archive/
2. Install DDK tool
3. Compile npf driver only
4. Copy npf.sys to `%systemroot%/System32/drivers`
5. Add Registry Info to register above
6. ***Reboot is important***